# save features from openlayers to postgis via nodejs and websockets

Tags: node.js, postgresql, websocket, openlayers, postgis

I am trying to save features created on a vector layer (openlayers) to postgreSQL 9.1/postGIS 2.0 via websockets. I'm using websockets because I'm inserting form data, along with the geometry.

My server is NodeJS 0.10.12 and the pg module.

I am trying to convert a feature's geometry to a string, strip it from the letters and the parentheses and send to the server only the numbers. I get syntax errors on the server side, about the geometry.

I cannot fix it despite trying many things and different syntaxes.

Client side (snippet)

```
//create websockets
var so = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000");

//error report for websockets   
      so.onerror=function (evt) 
     {saveMSG.textContent = evt;}

//open websockets
 so.onopen = function(){
//get geometry      
 var jak=map.layers[2].features[0].geometry;
//make it a string      
 var as=new String(jak);
//keep the numbers      
 var hul=as.substring(11,as.length-1);
//make it WKT       
 var god=hul.toString();


//send it with stringify/websockets
       so.send(JSON.stringify({command: 'insertAll',
       geo: god,
//send other things from the form....
```

And the server side

```
var packet = JSON.parse(msg.utf8Data);
switch (packet['command']) 
{case 'insertAll':insertEm(packet['geo']) ;break;
//other cases here...call function according to case...
//so "insertAll" calls the following

function insertEm(geo){
//get client data, put them in place and create a string
var met="ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING("+geo+")',900913)";
var pra=new String(met);

//connect to db and execute prepared statement
var conString = "pg://user:user@localhost:5432/myDB";

var client = new pg.Client(conString);
client.connect();

var query = client.query({name:"inser", text:"INSERT INTO pins(p_geom) values($1)", values:[pra]});
```

I get the error :
 `[error: parse error - invalid geometry] hint: '"ST"<-- parse error a position 2 within geometry']`

So I thought maybe its prepared statements fault?

I have switched it to a simple query, like:

`var query = client.query("INSERT INTO pins (p_geom) values('"+pra+"')")`

and I get the error

`[error: syntax error at or near "LINESTRING"]`

At the end of the query I put 
`query.on("end", function (result) {console.log(result);connection.send(pra); client.end();});`

So I can see what the clients send to the server. I get

`ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2335859.0225 4725430.1340625,2378933.155 4741356.7040625)',900913)`

Which looks fine...

Any suggestions? I really dont know how to fix this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this query:

`var query = client.query("INSERT INTO pins (p_geom) values('"+pra+"')")`

you should not be quoting `pra`.  This will quote the ST_GeomFromText function call, and your submitted query will be something like:

`var query = client.query("INSERT INTO pins (p_geom) values('ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2335859.0225 4725430.1340625,2378933.155 4741356.7040625)',900913)')")`

PostGIS thinks you are trying to submit a poorly formatted string, with unescaped single quotes in the middle of it.

Switching your query string builder to do this *should* work:

`var query = client.query("INSERT INTO pins (p_geom) values("+pra+")")`

**BUT DON'T DO THIS**

You are now opening yourself up to a SQL injection attack because someone may hack the HTTP request to send something sneaky instead of the geometry WKT you are expecting.  Don't use string concatenation to embed input from a web browser into your database query because it bypasses some safety features of your framework.

Now, back to your first attempt to use a parameterized query:

The node.js library is trying to prepare your parameter for insertion into the DB, and is treating it like a String, surrounding it with single quotes, and escaping all embedded single quotes.   This causes the query to be sent to PostGIS as:

`INSERT INTO pins(p_geom) values('ST_GeomFromText(''LINESTRING(2335859.0225 4725430.1340625,2378933.155 4741356.7040625)'',900913)')`

PostGIS then helpfully tries to convert the string to a geometry by parsing it, and complains that a valid geometry wouldn't start with "ST"

Instead of passing `ST_GeomFromText(...)` as a String parameter, **just pass the part of the query that is really a string - the WKT**.   Something like this:

`var wkt = "LINESTRING("+geo+")";`

`var query = client.query('INSERT INTO pins(p_geom) values(ST_GeomFromText(?,900913))', [wkt])`

Comment: @Ireeder What an amazing anser. So detailed and analytical. Thank you for giving the solution. It worked with `var met="LINESTRING("+geo+")";` and then `var query = client.query({name:"inser", text:"INSERT INTO pins(p_name, p_descr,p_geom) values($1,$2,ST_GeomFromText($3,900913))", values:[name, descr,met]});`. I never thought to check the quotes.  I was struggling for days. [I'm so happy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=-Ijw6t7tPww&t=14). Thanks.

Comment: @slevin Thanks, glad it helped.  I actually haven't done any node.js, but have done lots of PostGIS, and most ORM frameworks regardless of language do the same things.

Comment: Sorry to drag this up 10 YEARS LATER but with the parameterized query as per slevin's comment, I was getting error "Could not determine data type of parameter". 
Fixed this by explicitly describing the type using `ST_GeomFromText($3::text,900913)`. Hope this helps anyone else stumbling across it.